# How to get the XYZ values from accelerometer via beacon

Tags: beacon, ruuvitag

I was checking the [Sensor Protocol for Eddystone-URL](https://github.com/ruuvi/sensor-protocol-for-eddystone-url) for beacon specifications. Currently it looks that its only giving out weather related data, anyway, I would be more interested on getting the accelerometer data.

Thus is there any easy way on getting the XYZ values from accelerometer via the beacon ?

or any other ways, such as BLE Characteristics  to get the data in real time ?

Comment: Your link is missing.

Answer (score 1):

The RuuviTag is under active development, and the software is by no means feature complete yet. As of right now, accelerometer driver is being developed and tested, and it will take a while to create a service which presents the data over bluetooth characteristic.

I have added [task on our Trello board](https://trello.com/c/Lek1p6jl) to add a service which has the Accelerometer characteristics, you can vote on it to help us prioritize the development of features.